# Is there a Cloud Spanner framework forthcoming?

Tags: frameworks, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I started looking at Google's Cloud Spanner and it certainly looks interesting.

Since ruby has rails, MongoDB has Meteor, and RethinkDB has Horizon, is there any talk about Cloud Spanner having some sort of dedicated framework, or is any existing framework adapting to Cloud Spanner?

Or is Cloud Spanner much too new to even consider this yet?

Comment: why did my question get a down-vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [feathersJs](https://feathersjs.com) will be the first framework to support spanner:

https://github.com/perimetral/feathers-spanner-connector

Feathers already supports just about every database i know of, since it already supports many ORM's (waterline, sequelize, knex, etc) in addition to mongodb & rethink.

Answer (score 1):

We don't plan to create a Cloud Spanner-specific framework, but hope to integrate it into all the existing ORMs and popular frameworks.

The open-source community is already working on integration into Ruby/Rails via [ActiveRecord](https://github.com/supership-jp/activerecord-spanner-adapter) with our support. There are projects for JBDC, JPA and eventually Hibernate as a result. We hope there are similar projects for Python, Node, PHP etc.

Long term, we hope that Cloud Spanner is just another database that is a support engine for all the ORMs and frameworks that people want to work with.

Comment: has anybody looked into interfacing spanner with node-sequelize?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how you can integrate Google Cloud Spanner into existing frameworks like SpringBoot / JPA / Hibernate: https://github.com/olavloite/spanner-jpa-example

Answer (score 0):

We just released an EF Core provider for the Google Spanner db: https://github.com/NoGame/NG.Data.Spanner

If it might be relevant to anyone...

Comment: i am wondering if sequelize (https://sequelizejs.com) ORM is being considered as well.