# using google spanner and sequelize.js

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sequelize.js, google-cloud-spanner

is there any consideration using spanner with [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/)?   sequelize currently works with mariadb(mysql), postgresql, and a couple others.  and we just learned that sequelize now works with [Cockroachdb via node/npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-cockroachdb)

previously i asked a [spanner framework question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034913/is-there-a-google-spanner-framework-forthcoming):

[github reply to question](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7347)

Answer (score 1):

This is in the feature requests backlog but isn't being actively developed. We do hope to support most popular ORMs eventually. As you saw in [the other reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034913/is-there-a-google-spanner-framework-forthcoming), the open source community is developing an [ActiveRecord](https://github.com/supership-jp/activerecord-spanner-adapter) adaptor and hopefully more projects like these start as the product matures.

Comment: thanks - i had hoped that google might put a little of its mighty clout behind sequelize.  i would love to try spanner using sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

it appears that there is little activity with activerecord.

some have said that sequelize is already been overly-modified for newer databases.  here is a new connector for the [feathers](http://feathersjs.com) framework:

https://github.com/perimetral/feathers-spanner-connector